# select numeric columns and one column specified by name from data frame

Tags: r, scale, numeric

I have a data frame which contains both numeric and non-numeric columns, say

```
df <- data.frame(v1=1:20,v2=1:20,v3=1:20,v4=letters[1:20],v5=letters[1:20])
```

To select only the non-numeric columns I would use

```
fixCol <- !sapply(df,is.numeric)
```

But now I also want to include a specific numeric column, say v2. My data frame is very big and the order of the columns changes, so I cannot index it using a number, I really want to use the name 'v2'. I tried

```
fixCol$v2 = TRUE
```

but that gives me the warning `In fixCol$FR = TRUE : Coercing LHS to a list` which makes it impossible to subset my original data frame to get only fixCol

```
df[,fixCol]
```

gives: `Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'`

In the end my goal is to scale all numeric columns of my data frame except this one specified column, using something like this

```
scaleCol = !fixCol
df_scaled = cbind(df[,fixCol], sapply(df[,scaleCol],scale))
```

How can I best do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a OR condition (`|`) to get a logical index and then subset the columns of 'df'.

```
df1 <- df[!sapply(df, is.numeric)|names(df)=='v2']
head(df1,2)
#  v2 v4 v5
#1  1  a  a
#2  2  b  b
```

Comment: this works great, thanks! How do I make df2 which contains all columns NOT put in df1, without reversing the whole sapply statement? I tried df2 <- df[,!names(df1)] or df2 <- df[,-c(names(df1))] but both give an error.
I need df2 as well in order to be able to scale df2 and put it in a new dataframe together with df1.

Comment: @Ciska We can either use `setdiff` or `%in%` i.e. `df2 <- df[setdiff(names(df), names(df1))]`

Answer (score 2):

```
fixCol <- !sapply(df,is.numeric)
fixCol <- df[, fixCol]
fixCol$v2 <- df[colnames(df)=="v2"]
head(fixCol)
 # v4 v5 v2
#1  a  a  1
#2  b  b  2
#3  c  c  3
#4  d  d  4
#5  e  e  5
#6  f  f  6
```

Comment: thanks, this works! The answer from akrun uses a little less lines but I am happy with both. Thanks again!